# Using Commands in OCX library in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ocx

Im trying to write a script in matlab which interfaces with an old piece of hardware. The serial I/O routines were written in BASIC and are contained in a .ocx file. Previously these were called in a VB6 script.

I would like to be able to call the scripts in the .ocx file from within matlab and do all the post processing from there. I have researched activex controls in matlab, but those seem focussed on GUIs and things like that.

Is there a way of importing these functions into matlab? or is it necessary to compile the functions as something else?

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `actxcontrol` function for this.  See:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/actxcontrol.html

ActiveX controls (aka *.ocx) were usually intended for GUI purposes, but they don't have to be.  `actxcontrol` has a number of constructors - you only need the first, which takes only the control's `progid` (the other overloads specify position, which is for GUI-type controls).

You would then use the `interfaces` and `invoke` functions to call methods in your OCX.

Comment: Obligatory comment: ActiveX/OCX is some seriously outdated technology. This might be a good opportunity for you to take the logic encapsulated in the BASIC code and move it to something more modern (and that you could then get a few more years' worth of work out of).

Comment: Thanks very much for you help! You're definitely right about this all being outdated. Unfortunately time is a factor at the moment so a short-term solution is needed. As we do not have any documentation regarding the serial communication except what is contained within the BASIC code (of which I have no experience). Which is why we want to use the existing library.

Comment: @James: I understand your situation, which is why I won't recommend the alternative, which is to compile your Matlab code as a .Net assembly and incorporate it into a C# application that handles the serial port stuff. This is sort of the exact opposite of what you're currently doing, which is to encapsulate the serial port stuff as a COM object and include it in your Matlab application.